# How to show only one column after sorting in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table called 'customers', and I have to sort it first by country and by city, which I  have successfully done.

Using this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
ORDER BY Country, City
```

But from the output that I have, how do I print only the list of cities?

My table has several attributes or columns such as companyName, contactName, etc...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT City FROM customers ORDER BY Country, City
```

Replace `*` with the columns you want to show - `City`in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The SELECT criteria determines the columns displayed, while the WHERE criteria determines what rows are displayed :)

In your case it would be: SELECT City FROM customers ORDER BY Country, City

The * represents a 'wildcard' which in this case means display all.

If you wished to display both Country and city it would be:SELECT City, Country FROM customers ORDER BY Country, City

The order of the columns is determined by which order you write them in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the specific column names instead of * , which indicates all the column names.

e.g.

```
SELECT City FROM customers
ORDER BY Country, City
```